# flutter DataTable multiline wrapping and centering

Tags: flutter, datatable

I'm trying to have multiple, centered lines in the DataColumn() row of a DataTable() in flutter.  It seems, though, that there is no support for centering or for multiple lines.

My DataTable Code looks something like this:

```
class TestDayData extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> timesList = [
    "This is",
    "a bunch",
    "of strings",
  ];

  final String day;

  TestDayData({Key key, this.day}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
            label: Center(child: Text(day)),
            numeric: false,
          ),
        ],
        rows: timesList
            .map(
              (times) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(times.toString()),
                ),
              ]),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I made a dartpad file here to show the above code in a larger context. (the reason that I am putting multiple DataTables in a Row widget, instead of using one DataTable for all of the days, is because I plan on putting each of them into a Stack widget so that I can overlay appointments on top of the columns.)

https://dartpad.dev/44bbb788e0d5f1e6393dd38a29430981

So far, I can approximate a multi-lined, centered DataColumn row by adding spaces and using a newline character as seen in the dartpad file.  (but there has to be a better way!)

Comment: Great question, did you find a better solution for the multiline text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `textAlign` property in `Text` widget

```dart
DataTable(
  showCheckboxColumn: false,
  columns: [
    DataColumn(
      label: Center(child: Text(day, textAlign:TextAlign.center)),
        numeric: false,
      ),
    ],
    rows: timesList
      .map((times) => DataRow(cells: [
         DataCell(
           Text(times.toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
         ),
      ]),
    )
    .toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 7):

For me on the `DataColumn`, using the `Center` widget or the `textAlign` property on the `Text` widget didn't work:

this is my solution:

```
DataColumn(
  label: Expanded(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [Text("text")],
    ),
  ),
),
```

`DataCell` worked just fine with the `Center` widget

Comment: in my case, in Data_table_2 it caused a layout error . so I used Center Widget in both DataColumn and DataCell

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the solution.

you just need to wrap the text with `Center` widget and then wrap it again with `Expanded` widget just like this:

```
DataTable(
          columns: [
                   DataColumn(label: Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('ID', textAlign: TextAlign.center,))),),
                   DataColumn(label: Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('name', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)))),
                   ]
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to center your text in Datacolumn

```
DataColumn(
label: Center( widthFactor: 1.4,
child: Text("HELLO", textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,),),)),
```

You can try this to center your text in Datacell for rows.

```
DataCell( Center(child: Text("Hello")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to centralize:

```
     Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PaginatedDataTable(
                source: data,
                header: const Center(child: Text('My Products')),
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Price'))
                ],
                columnSpacing: 100,
                horizontalMargin: 10,
                rowsPerPage: 8,
                showCheckboxColumn: false,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```